# Is it possible to change value on base class when the same field gets changed on it's derived class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, derived-class

I'm using Unity here. My question is, is it possible to change value on base class when the same field gets changed on it's derived class? and vice-versa

I will give an example to make it clear:

```
public class BaseClass : MonoBehaviour{
    public int x;
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass{
    //-------------
}

public class AnotherClass : MonoBehaviour{
    GameObject player = Instantiate(playerModel) as GameObject;  //Assume playerModel is refrenced or something

    DerivedClass example = player.GetComponent<DerivedClass>();

    example.x = 5;
}
```

In this case `player.GetCompenent<DerivedClass >().x` will print 5, but  `player.GetCompenent<BaseClass >().x` will print 0.
Is there a way to have BaseClass X equal to 5?
Without directly setting it to 5

Comment: Have you added both components to your GameObject ?

Comment: Sounds like the two calls to GetComponent are returning two different instances.  If they were the same instance, by the rules of inheritance, the values should be equal

Comment: It is possible and your code looks right. Please show how you are printing it in your code that results to 0. Just provide the exact code example you are using.

Comment: If it is as tatmanblue says, this is due to having BOTH classes attached to your game object and the GetComponent call is grabbing different ones. If you only have ONE attached, show the inspector for your GameObject.

Comment: I only have the DerivedClass class on my GameObject

Comment: Trying to print the value of X in a totally another script that has a reference to the player GameObject. So when I call player.GetComponent<DerivedClass>().x this prints 5 but player.GetCompenent<BaseClass >().x prints 0! Again these print functions on another 4th class not mentioned above